# Setting a MutationObserver on a shadow root element

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, mutation-observers

I'm currently trying to observe an element inside a shadow root that is populated when an error has occurred within the application. I'm targetting an element that's body is **empty** on page loads

```
<div id="errorContainer"></div>
```

however when an error occurs, is populated with `div`'s. The structure of which looks like the following:

[image: Image of DevTools DOM]

Currently, when the page loads I have a function that is called `checkforShadow()` which gets the shadow root parent, gets the id of the element inside the shadow root I want to observe and initialises the observer.

```
const searchModule = document.querySelector('.campaign-map');
const searchModuleRoot = searchModule && searchModule.shadowRoot;

var errorContainer = searchModuleRoot.querySelector('#errorContainer');

// Create an observer instance.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log(errorContainer.innerText);   
});

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options.
observer.observe(errorContainer , {
    attributes:    true,    // Monitor attribute changes
    childList:     true,    // Monitor child nodes of errorContainer
    subtree:       true,    // Monitor errorContainer and it's decendants for new/ removed child nodes
    characterData: true     // Monitor errorContainer (and it's children) for character changes
});
```

My understanding is that seeing as I have the `childList` and the `subtree` set as true, when `errorContainer` is populated, I should be able to see it log to the console.

I've also tried added a `debugger` into the observer instance however it never seems to get into it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The element is simply replaced with the new one, so observing it won't help. Observe something above it e.g. `root-wrapper` .

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately replacing `errorContainer` with `searchModule` in the `observe` still does not seem to work

Comment: @JamesS - I suspect they meant something like `root-wrapper` -- inside the shadow DOM, but not something that's likely to be completely replaced with a new version of the element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah you're right! I'd added a `debugger;` in the `observe` and it has hit it. Thanks

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @wOxxOm and @t-j-crowder said.

Although I was observing the errorContainer, when an error occurred, it was replacing the container instead of adding elements to it.

After adding the observer to an element inside the shadow root which was not replaced, I was able to transcend the DOM and determine whether or not the error container was being populated or not.